# Draw diagram by call stack

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, diagram

Does any one know how to draw a class diagram by call stack in VS2010?

Comment: Thats two diffrent concepts a call stack is a view of a running program a class diagram is a view of how classes are structured.

Comment: Yes I know. I need just visualize some process when I in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rerun said, the question in itself doesn't make much sense, perhaps you mean a [Sequence Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram)? If so, you can't directly create it from the CallStack window, but you can create it from the code editor [as described here](http://andrewtwest.com/2010/04/20/visual-studio-2010-helps-you-grok-other-peoples-code-quickly/).

Answer (score 1):

The closest built-in thing to what you want is the **Parallel Stacks debug window**, which can be accessed via the Debug menu, Windows menu.

It doesn't exactly give you a seperate box for each item in the call chain, but at least it's visual and easier to visually parse than the call stack window.

Be sure to turn on the **Method View**.

It also allows navigation to the methods in the call stack.